# how to configure phabricator with a non root url?

Tags: apache, phabricator

I am trying to install phabricator behind apache http server. The problem is that i would like to have an url like

http://myserver.fr.xxxx/phabricator and not http://myserver.fr.xxxx/

i have tried several configuration in apache but i am not able to have phabricator working correctly (alias,redirect).

Is there any solution with a tricky apache configuration or phabricator future release to handle this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported, and we do not plan to support it. The install documentation should probably make this more clear, although it is mentioned in the Configuration Guide:

> You can either install Phabricator on a subdomain (like
>   phabricator.example.com) or an entire domain, but you can not install
>   it in some subdirectory of an existing website.

We don't plan to support this because support would be complex and have security implications, and only a tiny number of very small installs would benefit.

Comment: This sucks.  Thanks for the clear answer though.  That is all.

Comment: Update: Got it going on root path with zero trouble.  Great software, thanks Evan for open sourcing it.

Comment: @moodboom Could you please provide steps how you achieved this? We are stucked on this for a while

Comment: @VladoDemcak I followed Evan's advice and registered a new domain and installed phabricator on the root there.  Evan is king of phabricator and if he says it's not supported and there are security implications, it's not supported and there are security implications.  :-)  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the following in the root of my apache config file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/phabricator/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/phabricator/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/phabricator/(.+)$          /phabricator/index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
```

However, I can't fully test it because my computer doesn't seem to think ./bin/storage is a valid executable so I can't setup the database behind it.

It seems to work so far, but I'm not sure if the phabricator php code will just work or of it will need some modification as well.  (when I visit MYHOST/phabricator/index.php, I get a phabricator error page related to the missing mysql setup)