# How to configure phabricator with a bare domain url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lan, phabricator

I'm trying to run phabricator on my home server. The last thing I struggle with is to use phabricator with a bare url. I've set up a virtual host (apache 2.4) using a seperate port for phabricator and added the required rewrite rules:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phabricator/phabricator/webroot
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
 <Directory "/var/www/html/phabricator/phabricator/webroot">
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately, phabricator demands a non-root url. Any ideas?

I get the following error message: [image: error-message]

User **moodboom** found a solution but did not post the answer at [how-to-configure-phabricator-with-a-non-root-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720579/how-to-configure-phabricator-with-a-non-root-url).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it demands a non-root URL from the post you pointed to. It looks like the reverse, it demands a root URL. As quoted in the answer you mentioned:

> You can either install Phabricator on a subdomain (like
>   phabricator.example.com) or an entire domain, but you can not install
>   it in some subdirectory of an existing website.

Comment: I thought so as well, but phabricator still refused to work. See attached screenshot ;-(

Comment: What are you visiting the site as? You just need to set something like `ServerName local.example.com` in your `VirtualHost` and make sure `local.example.com` is set up in your `/etc/hosts` file to point to `127.0.0.1` and that should fix it. You don't need to use a different port then, you can just use 80 on your chosen hostname. Visit the site as `local.example.com` in your browser and change `example.com` as appropriate when following these instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Since there wasn't any easy way to solve this, I hat to set up a local DNS server (dnsmasq) to get rid of this problem. Manually changing the host file on every single client is possible but too tedious and error prone. Dnsmasq on the other hand was easy to setup on ubuntu 16.04 and will keep my local network a bit more organized.

Cheers,

O.Schmitz